# Separate data in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset with two columns where I want to separate the second one (delimited by |) into many columns.

```
id     column
1       a|b|a
2       a|b|c|d|e
3       a|c|c
```

I would like to have columns with the name of each item and its count.
for example for user 1 it would be as follows:

```
id    a    b     c     d     e
1     2    1     0     0     0
2     1    1     1     1     1
```

How do I get to separate this data such that the values are distributed in columns as such?

Comment: @Cettt is there anyway I can separate the column such that the column has the name of the item (for example a) and the observation would have the count? for example if id 1 has a|a|a, I want a column a for that user with a count of 3

Comment: you should ask this as a new question and write your title based on it. I don't think you have a duplicate question, but your current title makes your question sound like a duplicate.